# Dynamically added file to public directory is not accessible from browser - Meteor application

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am trying to upload the files in public directory

> (web.browser/app)

and trying to access the file on browser.But browser wont serve the files added on the run time.

However, I added a static file in the public directory, built the application and deployed. Static file is accessible from browser.

After some research I came across

> program.json inside web.broswer (in development server, not in local
>   server)

which has paths and urls mapping to files inside public directory(web.browser/app/).

My question is how to configure so that program.json gives access to all the files inside public directory(web.browser/app/) ? Or do we have any other way to access dynamically added files inside public directory ? I am trying not to use any third party storages like S3, also dont want to run another server to serve static files from public directory(web.browser/app/)

Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By storing uploaded files in system's **tmp** folder and serving them through **nginx** would solve this issue.

Comment: That may be a reasonable solution, but wouldn't be `the meteor way`.

Comment: yes, that would not be meteor way, but still a better way as it cost nothing extra :)

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to serve resources dynamically added to the `public` folder, because `meteor` actually includes static assets at compile time, and adds these routes manually.  Moreover, Meteor doesn't actually run in your project folder, but actually in `.meteor/local`, so it wouldn't know where to find these files in the first place.

As for a solution; there is a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29997394/how-to-create-dynamic-assets-in-meteor) for this question, but I don't think it is necessarily the best way to go about it anymore.  [Picker](https://github.com/meteorhacks/picker) has a cool feature, which is that it allows you to use `express` middleware.  You can easily use [Express static middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) to serve static files, so by combining these two, you should be able to dynamically serve the contents of a directory.

Comment: I was storing the files inside .meteor/local only as after deployment, it would point to web.browser which is inside .meteor/local.
And I don't want to introduce express in meteor just to upload and retrieve files.

Comment: @AnoopGoudar unfortunately there isn't really any other way.  Meteor doesn't have server-side routing by default, so you need to add some functionality to perform this.